# How to compare items in list to find odd numbers and print them?

Tags: python, function

The problem below uses the function get_numbers() to read a number of integers from the user. Three unfinished functions are defined, which should print only certain types of numbers that the user entered. Complete the unfinished functions, adding loops and branches where necessary. Match the output with the below sample:

Numbers are: 5 99 -44 0 12

I already figured out how to complete first function.
Having a hard time complete odd and negative number comparison.

For some reason

```
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    if numbers % 2 == 1:
    print('Odd numbers:', numbers)
```

Is not working?

```
size = 6

def get_numbers(num):
    numbers = []
    user_input = input('Enter %s integers:\n' % num)

    i = 0
    for token in user_input.split():
        number = int(token)     # Convert string input into integer
        numbers.append(number)  # Add to numbers list

        print(i, number)
        i += 1

    return numbers

def print_all_numbers(numbers):
    # Print numbers
    print('Numbers:')

def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    # Print all odd numbers
    print('Odd numbers:')

def print_negative_numbers(numbers):
    # Print all negative numbers
    print('Negative numbers:')

nums = get_numbers(size)
print_all_numbers(nums)
print_odd_numbers(nums)
print_negative_numbers(nums)

Enter 5 integers:
0 5
1 99
2 -44
3 0
4 12
Numbers: 5 99 -44 0 12
Odd numbers: 5 99
Negative numbers: -44
```

Comment: Think, if `numbers` is a list, does `numbers % 2` make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't working because `numbers` is a list of numbers. Try this code:

```
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    print('Odd numbers: ')
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            print(n, end=' '))
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    odd = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 1]
    print('Odd numbers:', ' '.join(map(str, odd)))
```

Comment: I had a typo in the answer, just fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

modulus needs to be == 0 to seen as an even and if number%2 != 0 then itll be read as an odd number

Comment: The remainder will be `1` if the number is odd. They're correct. Both ways will work.